# Probability Proof $P(B-A) =P(B)-P(A\cap B)$

Tags: probability, proof-writing

How would I go about proving this statement:

$P(B-A) =P(B)-P(A\cap B)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $(B-A) \cup (A \cap B) = B$ and $(B-A) \cap (A \cap B) = \emptyset.$

So $P(B) = P((B-A) \cup (A \cap B)) = P(B-A) + P(A \cap B).$ Therefore $P(B-A) = P(B) - P(A \cap B).$

Comment: Thank you @Dbchatto67

Comment: You are most welcome @KaliTheGreat.

Comment: sorry to pop up again, but I observed that $(*) (B−A)∪(A∩B)=B$, but in addition, I'm struggling to write a formal proof of that (*) observation. so far I've tried algebra of sets laws but with no success.

Comment: $$\begin{align} (B-A) \cup (A \cap B) & = (B \cap A^c) \cup (A \cap B). \\ & = (B \cup (A \cap B)) \cap (A^c \cup (A \cap B)). \\ & = B \cap ((A^c \cup A) \cap (A^c \cup B)). \\ & = B \cap (A^c \cup B). \\ & = B. \end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Use $P(X)+P(Y)=P(X\cap Y)+P(X\cup Y)$ with $X:=B-A,\,Y:=A\cap B$ so $X\cap Y=\emptyset,\,X\cup Y=B$.

Comment: Thank you @J.G.

Comment: @J.G. you made a small typo, there should be a minus in front of $P(X\cap Y)$.

Comment: @StanTendijck Not so. Draw a Venn diagram.

Comment: Oh I am sorry, you are right.